# Macbook keyboard's ] n } keys are cap locking

Tags: keyboard, macbook

I have replaced my MacBook keyboard twice and I continue to have the same issue. When I press the ] n } key it just turns on Caps Lock. I really need these keys to code.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Does this happen with both external keyboards and the built-in keyboard, or just one or the other?

Comment: Does this happen for other user accounts on your machine? Does this also happen when you boot from your Mac OS X DVD, during setup?

Comment: I don’t know enough about Macs, but I would assume that they too support multiple keyboard layouts, especially on a laptop. It sounds like a different layout has been accidentally selected. Someone with more Mac knowledge would need to explain how to choose the keyboard layout (hotkey? ‘control panel’ applet?) and probably how to remove the other ones.

Answer (score 1):

You should install [PCKeyboardHack](http://download.cnet.com/PCKeyboardHack/3000-2110_4-75363152.html) and change the keycode of the capslock key to 30 (keycode of "]" button). Next you have to switch off caps lock in keyboard settings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I find with a MacBook keyboard is that I can hit the caps lock key when I'm typing fast or carelessly (usually instead of the A key, sometimes instead of the left shift key).  Could your trouble be that with the '}' key, you hit the  caps lock instead of the shift key just below it?  That doesn't explain the problem with the ']' key.

What is your language and keyboard settings set to?  Have you accidentally done something with the keyboard shortcuts from 'System Preferences' / 'Keyboard and Mouse'?

Comment: Note that in Snow Leopard, the preference pane you want is simply titled "Keyboard".